# Locking down SFTP user in cygwin

Tags: ssh, permissions, cygwin, sftp

I set up a user to  ssh to Windows Server 2008 R2.

I was able to change de default directory.

The only piece I could not figure out is how to restrict user to just that directory.

In other word I don't want the user to be able to change directory.

Please advise.

EDIT:

This is where I stand:

- Cygwin Installed
- User (`James`) created in windows
- Group (SftpUser) created in windows
- `SftpUser` is not showing in /etc/passwd
- instead there is some `None` group which James is a member of
- I can login with my user
- `cygdrive` and `dev` directory are listed ( I do not want this)
- `cygdrive` is empty

---

Here is the scenario

I want `James` of `sftpUser` group to be restricted to its upload folder.
The path is on an external drive:

```
D:\uploads\james_folder\
```

in cygwin

```
/cygdrive/d/uploads/james_folder/
```

I dont mind having the restriction on

```
/home/james/upload
```

And then mount the directory in the home path but it seems cygwin is not bundled with samba.

**sshd_config**

```
Match user james
    ChrootDirectory /home/james/upload/
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Comment: I think the right way to do this is by setting the appropriate ACLs to deny James access to almost everything.

Comment: @Gilles thanks for your suggestion, how do I go about doing that

Comment: If I knew, I'd have written an answer. I'm not a Windows expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I setup the SFTP over cygwin recently and I realised that we cannot hide the following directories:

- /cygdrive
- /dev

As you may be aware that the /path/to/sftp has to be root-owned that are not writeable by any other user or group, you need to update the user id in /etc/passwd to 0 because there is no root concept in Windows.

If you jail the user to non-cygdrive (e.g. /sftp), you will only see /cygdrive (nothing will be appeared under /cygdrive).

If you jail the user to cygdrive (e.g. /cygdrive/d/.../sftp), you will see /cygdrive/d. However, you cannot change to any parent directory if you set it up correctly.

Hope the above information helps!

---

Please check the following things:

1. Make sure the user id of the the current user logging in (james in your example) in /etc/passwd is zero. It is because cygwin will change the user of all the directories under root as the current user logging in. Please run the `ls -l /` command to verify.
2. Make sure /home, /home/james, /home/james/upload is the current user owned (i.e. equivalent to root-owned with user id 0).
3. Make sure /etc/sshd_config contains:

   ```
   Match user james
   ChrootDirectory /home/james/upload/
   ForceCommand internal-sftp
   ```

Comment: `if you set it up correctly.` can you please elborate ?

Comment: please see the additional information I added and see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to setup a `ChrootDirectory` directory in [sshd_config](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5)

Detailed instructions for ArchLinux are available at [SFTP chroot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot).

The basic outline is as follows:

1) Add chroot configuration to `sshd_confg` such as:

```
Match User username
ChrootDirectory /home/%u
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

2) Change chroot directory rights with something like:

```
chown root.root /home/<user>
usermod -d / <user>
```

3) Fixing path for authorized_keys with something like:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

A [post](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2008-12/msg00005.html) over at the cygwin mailing list reports success using this method to restrict access with a similar configuration as above.

Comment: I have read that chroot does not work with cygwin but i give it a try now thanks

Comment: `-bash: usermod: command not found` and `chown: invalid user: âroot.rootâ` is what i get

Comment: It is unlikely you need these commands, but root.root would be something like administrator.administrators since there is generally not a root user and group in Windows. As for the usermod not existing in cygwin, I'd suggest just manually editing /etc/passwd and changing the home directory of the restricted user to /

Comment: but see the directory I want to give access is `/cygdrive/d/UPLOAD/user_folder/` can you please adjust your answer to to this path? and you right there is no root user. +1

Comment: the commands now works , but when I test i get `sshd: PID 4332: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/"` in the server log, im not sure why it points to root directory

Comment: This error indicates the directory permissions are not secure enough. From the post I linked to: `All directories from root to the chroot directory must be owned by UID 0 and GID 0. For example, if you want to jail users in /jail then / and /jail must belong to (0, 0). In my setup, I set Administrator user to be (0, 0) in /etc/passwd.` Have you changed the uid/gid of administrator in /etc/passwd to 0?

Comment: I cant change all theses folders because its in the D drive, and thats owned by the `SYSTEM` account.

Comment: I opened the passwd file in vi and I changed the pid and gid to 0

Comment: Great, now make sure / is owned by administrator.administrator and do the same for each directory in the path up to /path/to/jaildir. Then restart sshd and attempt to connect again to see if you still get the fatal error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16806/discussion-between-meda-and-ssnobody).

Comment: I still struggle with this question, anyhelp is appreciated, I added a bounty

Comment: I commented in chat. What is the current error you're getting? Also, you ask for a secure solution, but chroot on cygwin is NOT secure...